# Better user experience while having a small amount of content to show

Tags: lists, psychology, dynamic-ui

I have the below screen that shows a list of items. The list can sometimes be long and sometimes short. When the list is long, the UI looks okay, but when it is short, the screen looks a little boring. Is there any suggestion to improve the display in this scenario?

[image: Display of two phone mockups; one has only two items, the other has many]

Context:

- This is an app for a IOT device.
- This screen comes in the middle of the user guide/on-board screens.

Comment: White space is your friend. No need to add things just to make it busy.

Comment: I’m actually more concerned with the “high content” case. How do you make explicit to a user that they can scroll (or generally, view more), if there is more than one page with connections?

Comment: It's perfect as it is!!!

Comment: @Boldewyn, True. I was considering putting a scroll bar to the right side, but when I gave this screen to my dad (60+ years old), he scrolled it to find the missing WiFi. So I came to the conclusion that humans nowadays have adopted to scroll if the content is missing from the list.

Comment: Just add unicorns. Seriously, though, couldn't you use the "rubberband pull" effect to convey that there is no more content "below" the screen?

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica Hmm, interesting idea. I might implement that way so it'll convey that there is no more content when the list is short.

Comment: As well as the "low content" and "high content" cases, don't forget to properly handle the "no content" case where there are no wifi hotspots detected at all (what does user do next now?), or indeed the "plenty of content, but can't find MY router" case (is that because the user doesn't know the name of their router, or because it's off/not broadcasting SSID, or something else? Is there a button they need to press on their router when connecting a new device? etc.)

Comment: Just fill the space with hot singles looking to meet me in my area like any other sane developer.

Comment: I agree that less is more here; the original looks great. If I were using this interface, the only addition I might find helpful is a small note about how many networks were found, as a hint for when scrolling down is an option (maybe an approximation like "More than 15 networks found" or "20+ networks found" for high numbers)

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica And how can you get an idea, without dragging the list all the way down and up again, _how long_ the list is?  [redacted: long rant about discoverability and affordances and the needless crapness of modern UIs]

Comment: I literally saw a UI like this yesterday. I didn't notice the problem at all, unlike I can now. I didn't because my vision 'narrowed in' to the two WiFi networks and _I just didn't look at the bottom of my phone_. Where as today, now, I'm looking at _the entire of the phone_.

Comment: "the screen looks a little boring" — is choosing a wifi network meant to be exciting?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

#### The first screen isn't "boring," it's "focused."

A user will be task-driven and goal-oriented during this setup process. Rather than looking to be entertained or stimulated (as with a news or social media application), they're trying to get a task completed. If the user happens to see fewer options during this step, it will actually help them complete their tasks easier.

Comment: This answer put me in a different perspective.  I will show my screen and @Danielillo suggested screens to an end-user. So I can get feedback from them as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

A footer after the final list item (with, say, the number of results) may help indicate that the user has seen all the possible results.

[image: mockup with a list footer appended after the results.]

(Please excuse my art skills)

Comment: This is a very good idea! It helps the user know he is seeing all there is. Informative and to the point.

Comment: I don't like this - it seems redundant. What you *should* do, though, is put a throbber at the bottom if the device is still looking for more networks!

Answer (score 15):

### Watermark

[image]

### Individual framing

[image]

### Total framing

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to expand on how your suggestions improve the user's experience? These are just images.

Comment: This is great. Thanks for sharing your ideas. I think having a total frame will fill the empty space and will give the user some idea saying you have a little list.

Comment: In my opinion, all of these make the experience *worse*. They just add superfluous visual noise and do not make the content any clearer.

Comment: @CodyGray OP wanted to know what could be used to fill out the remaining space, which is exactly what this answer focuses on. The watermark solution does seem a little ancient, but it's still a sensible answer to the question. I can imagine many situations where your minimalistic ideal simply doesn't work and results in a more confusing UX, especially if there are 0-2 items in a list and the user may expect more to appear. Large flat color spaces look ugly and it's something you see much more often in amateurish Android applications than modern professional software.

Comment: @natiiix Empty gray boxes could just as easily be perceived as a gap where content is supposed to be.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms You're not wrong. It all depends on the user. Large white space, yikes. Of course, that is, as well, very much subjective, but I don't like the idea. I'd much rather either vertically center the content or add a footer to emphasize the end of the list.

Comment: @natiiix "OP wanted to know what could be used to fill out the remaining space" - But the OP would seem to be asking from a graphic-design perspective, not from a UX perspective.